# ERROR: Unable to start debugging. Unexpected LLDB output from command "-exec-run". When trying to debug C++ code in VSCode

Tags: c++, vscode-debugger

I started working on a beginners C++ course for game dev and last week the debug ran fine to run my code. Now, all of a sudden, I get this error when running debug

```
Warning: Debuggee TargetArchitecture not detected, assuming x86_64.
ERROR: Unable to start debugging. Unexpected LLDB output from command "-exec-run". process exited with status -1 (attach failed (Not allowed to attach to process.  Look in the console messages (Console.app), near the debugserver entries, when the attach failed.  The subsystem that denied the attach permission will likely have logged an informative message about why it was denied.))
The program '/Users/bcarson/Documents/GameDev/dapper-dasher/main' has exited with code 42 (0x0000002a).
```

I haven't changed anything only created a new project, and now my previous project won't run either. So confused, much frustrated, many annoyed.

I searched through the interwebs and found some related articles - most dealing with Macs running the M1 chip (I have an Intel chip) but tried their solution anyways, which was installing CodeLLDB extension on my VSCode. I added a config to my launch.json file for a CodeLLDB: Launch option and updated the program to `"${workspaceFolder}/main.cpp"`

launch.json file:

```
{
  // Use IntelliSense to learn about possible attributes.
  // Hover to view descriptions of existing attributes.
  // For more information, visit: https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=830387
      "version": "0.2.0",
      "configurations": [
        {
          "type": "lldb",
          "request": "launch",
          "name": "Launch",
          "program": "${workspaceFolder}/main.cpp",
          "args": [],
          "cwd": "${workspaceFolder}"
        },
        {
          "name": "Debug",
          "type": "cppdbg",
          "request": "launch",
          "program": "${workspaceFolder}/${fileBasenameNoExtension}",
          "args": [],
          "stopAtEntry": false,
          "cwd": "${workspaceFolder}",
          "environment": [],
          "externalConsole": false,
          "MIMode": "gdb",
          "setupCommands": [
            {
              "description": "Enable pretty-printing for gdb",
              "text": "-enable-pretty-printing",
              "ignoreFailures": false
            }
          ],
          "windows": {
            "miDebuggerPath": "C:/raylib/w64devkit/bin/gdb.exe",
          },
          "osx": {
            "MIMode": "lldb"
          },
          "linux": {
            "miDebuggerPath": "/usr/bin/gdb",
          },
          "preLaunchTask": "build debug"
        },
        {
          "name": "Run",
          "type": "cppdbg",
          "request": "launch",
          "args": [],
          "stopAtEntry": false,
          "cwd": "${workspaceFolder}",
          "environment": [],
          "externalConsole": false,
          "program": "${workspaceFolder}/${fileBasenameNoExtension}",
          "MIMode": "gdb",
          "windows": {
            "program": "${workspaceFolder}/${fileBasenameNoExtension}.exe",
            "miDebuggerPath": "C:/raylib/w64devkit/bin/gdb.exe"
          },
          "osx": {
            "MIMode": "lldb"
          },
          "linux": {
            "miDebuggerPath": "/usr/bin/gdb"
          },
          "preLaunchTask": "build release",
        }
      ]
    }
```

But I am still getting the same error. I tried removing all other launch.json configs but VSCode REALLY didn't like that.

Here are my mac specs:

```
macOS Monterey
Version 12.6.1

MacBook Pro (13-inch, 2019)
Processor 1.4 GHz Quad-Core Intel Core i5
```

Here are my VSCode specs:

```
Version: 1.74.1
Commit: 1ad8d514439d5077d2b0b7ee64d2ce82a9308e5a
Date: 2022-12-14T10:33:40.793Z
Electron: 19.1.8
Chromium: 102.0.5005.167
Node.js: 16.14.2
V8: 10.2.154.15-electron.0
OS: Darwin x64 21.6.0
Sandboxed: Yes
```

Here is my main.cpp file:

```
#include "raylib.h"

int main()
{
   //window dimensions
   const int windowWidth = 1300;
   const int windowHeight = 1300;
   //initialize the window
   InitWindow(windowWidth, windowHeight, "That Dasher Sure is Dapper!");

   SetTargetFPS(60);
   while (!WindowShouldClose())
   {
      //start drawing
      BeginDrawing();
      ClearBackground(WHITE);

      //stop drawing
      EndDrawing();
   }
   CloseWindow();
}
```

Comment: Welcome to the world of annoying software dev problems! One common problem is unspecific error messages which can be from many problems, and most of the help you'll find is about a cause that is not your situation, so you have a lot of noise in the way of finding a solution by searching. Also welcome to SO downvoting your question while offering no help. You are right that you have an Intel CPU so it's not the usual cause people post about. This bug isn't what your class is about, so I'd consult my professor for guidance. Maybe you can use VS (not Code), or XCode instead?

Comment: BTW, I made some effort to find other likely causes of this error for you, but did not find anything that looked likely to me. If you want to dig further, maybe see if you can find out what the output from LLDB was, and go from there.

Comment: @Dronz - Appreciate it. Just baffles me that it worked on Friday and now doesn't. I was thinking of switching over to xCode instead. I just currently use VSCode for work so it was just easier.

Comment: Image police in this case. I'm not a user of Mac or VS Code. I'd check to make sure you're not being jammed because there's already an instance of the program silently running in the background (shouldn't be a problem these days, but like I said, I don't know Mac) and how wide-spread this is by debugging a Hello World project. And if you haven't already, I'd take the error advice (*Look in the console messages (Console.app), near the debugserver entries, when the attach failed.*).

Comment: @billyc Yeah, as a developer with decades of experience . . . you are right, it's annoying, and it "should work", and the error feedback "should" be better documented, and it stinks when this sort of irrational failure happens, etc., but it does. Turn it on and off, Clean the projects, install updates, reinstall VSCode, try another machine, keep searching etc. Will your work projects debug?